# What is DenseVector?How is it used?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

Came up across the following code , but there is no namespace or type called DenseVector.Should I import anything?.I have already added `using System;`

```
 Vector<double> P1 = new DenseVector(new[] { PointA.x, PointA.y });
```

Comment: https://numerics.mathdotnet.com/api/MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double/DenseVector.htm

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe you forgot to insert this in your assembly references:

```
using MathNet.Numerics.LinearAlgebra.Double;
```

**Update:**

From this [link](https://answers.unity.com/questions/462042/unity-and-mathnet.html)

I got this working.

Steps:

- Create a folder called Assets/Plugins in your project.
- go to

https://onedrive.live.com/?id=84F3672F8CDA3E91%21440210&cid=84F3672F8CDA3E91

and download the latest version of MatNet.Numerics.dll in zip format.

- open the folder called Net35. Unity apparently only runs on this version of .net.
- copy BOTH MathNet.Numerics.dll AND System.Threading.dll into Assets/Plugins.

> Note: Don't touch anything in MonoDevelop. it should reference it automatically.

For me i was installing the newer .net version and I didn't realize it also needed System.Threading.dll. Once I got it in the above format it worked fine.

Comment: The type or namespace MathNet could not be found